# I can't find Notes on iCloud

Tags: backup, restore, notes.app

I had an iPhone 5c, backed up to the computer.

Then I also backed up my new iPhone 6s Plus.

Everything restored to my new iPhone except my Notes. I can't find them on iCloud, or on the computer either. How can I restore my Notes?

Answer (score 1):

First I want to know whether you can find notes on your iPhone 5c now, have you check your iPhone 5c? If the notes are still preserved on your iPhone 5c, upgrade iOS to the latest version and update iTunes. then you can try to backup them on your computer and iCloud again. If you have multiple email accounts each email account gets its own Notes account.